# React.js select lists are not holding the selected option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I have 2 `<select>` lists in my React.js application. They render fine, and are attached to a `handleChange` function. They are programmed to initially default to the first option.

When the user selects another option, the list visually seems to maintain the first option. However, when I submit the form and alert out the associated values in the state, it alerts the values selected by the user.

Here's my render function:

```
<div id="userActions">
  <form id="userActionsForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <label htmlFor="operator">Operator:</label>
    <select
      id="operator"
      name="operator"
      value={this.state.operator}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    >
      {this.state &&
        this.state.operators &&
        this.state.operators.map((op) => <option value={op}>{op}</option>)}
    </select>
    <label htmlFor="user">User:</label>
    <select
      id="user"
      name="user"
      value={this.state.user}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    >
      {this.state &&
        this.state.testUsers &&
        this.state.testUsers.map((tu) => <option value={tu}>{tu}</option>)}
    </select>
    <div className="submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    <span className="error">{this.state.error}</span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here's my `onChange` function:

```js
handleChange(event) {
  this.state.value = event.currentTarget.value;
  if (event.currentTarget.id === 'operator') {
    this.state.operator = event.currentTarget.value;
  } else if (event.currentTarget.id === 'user') {
    this.state.user = event.currentTarget.value;
  }
}
```

Here's my `onSubmit`:

```js
handleSubmit(event) {
  alert(this.state.user);
  alert(this.state.operator);
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: How does your constructor look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're mutating the state in `handleChange` by updating it like this `this.state.operator = event.currentTarget.value;`. You should **never ever** update the state directly. You need to use [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

I've just created a snippet for you below. You can click on "Run code snippet" and see it in action. I made the `handleChange` method simpler by using `event.target.name` as the key in the `state` object.

You also need to add a unique `key` prop for each child in a list (e.g. when you use `.map()`).

```js
const operators = ["op1", "op2", "op3"];
const testUsers = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    operator: operators[0],
    operators,
    testUsers,
    user: testUsers[0],
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log({
      user: this.state.user,
      operator: this.state.operator,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form id="userActionsForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="operator">Operator:</label>
        <select
          id="operator"
          name="operator"
          value={this.state.operator}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          {this.state.operators.map((operator) => (
            <option key={operator} value={operator}>
              {operator}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <label htmlFor="user">User:</label>
        <select
          id="user"
          name="user"
          value={this.state.user}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          {this.state.testUsers.map((user) => (
            <option key={user} value={user}>
              {user}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <div className="submit">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <span className="error">{this.state.error}</span>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```